# Android camera api SCENE_MODE_HDR not supported in Nexus 5?

Tags: android, android-camera, nexus-5, hdr

My Nexus 5 isn't supporting the HDR scene mode of the camera api (as well as the camera2 api). Is this due to the manufacturer support? If so, what I want to implement HDR scene mode in a custom camera app as in the stock camera?

I tried using both the camera APIs but none was supporting the SCENE_MODE_HDR parameter.

Using the `android.hardware.camera` api: (Logs HDR mode not supported)

```
List<String> sceneModes = params.getSupportedSceneModes();
if (sceneModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_HDR)) {
    Log.d("HDR", "HDR mode supported");
    params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_HDR);
} else {
    Log.d("HDR", "HDR mode not supported");
}
```

And using the `android.hardware.camera2` api: (Logs HDR mode not supported)

```
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
int[] sceneModes= characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AVAILABLE_SCENE_MODES);
boolean isHDRsupported = false;
for (int sceneMode : sceneModes) {
    if (sceneMode == CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_HDR) {
        isHDRsupported = true;
        break;
    }
}
Log.d("HDR", "HDR mode " + (isHDRsupported ? "" : "not ") + "supported");
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nexus 5 does not have support for an HDR scene mode.

The HDR+ mode in the included camera app is part of the application itself (there's a [blog post](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2014/10/hdr-low-light-and-high-dynamic-range.html) about how it works on top of the camera2 API).

Comment: Ohh. Thanks! So there is no way I can take HDR pictures using just the android camera APIs, right?

Comment: Not without implementing an HDR merge yourself, or getting a library from somewhere.  The hardware can certainly get you a fast burst of images with different settings to get the necessary data, it just won't do the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
cameraParameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_HDR);
camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
```

Comment: Yep, this will throw an exception that parameter not supported. It is ALWAYS recommended to check before setting the param whether the param is supported or not by getting the list of available modes.

Comment: Pleae try to query: SystemInfo.SupportsRenderTextureFormat(RenderTextureFormat.DefaultHDR)

Comment: which class is `SystemInfo`? I am talking about android api here

Comment: Apologies. My mistake. Can you please follow the below link. I hope it might help you: https://developer.android.com/samples/HdrViewfinder/src/com.example.android.hdrviewfinder/HdrViewfinderActivity.html

Comment: Or this (line 243 onwards): https://developer.android.com/samples/HdrViewfinder/src/com.example.android.hdrviewfinder/HdrViewfinderActivity.html

Comment: This is not meant to be an answer, you should post it as a comment. Links too are meant to be a comment unless you a code snippet. Kindly read the rules of answering on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Thanks!